# Load a custom div on slick-lighbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

All I have is a lightbox [`slick-lighbox`].

I don't need the image caption, I need a custom layout on the image carousel.

I have no idea how to display this, any suggestions?

[image: slick-lightbox screenshot]

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //$('.fill-box').fillBox();        
  $('.image-grid').slickLightbox();

  var $element = $('.image-grid li');

  $element.on('click', function () {           
    console.log('')
  });
  // ...
)};
```